# Does Bezout's lemma imply you can generate all integers from two co-prime integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does Bezout's lemma imply that:

$x\mathbb{Z} + y\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$? if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $y\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq0$ and gcd$(x,y)=1$ ($x$ or $y$ can be negative as well)?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Does it also hold for an arbitrary set on integers

Comment: @trienko No they must be coprime.

Comment: In general $a_1\Bbb Z+a_2\Bbb Z+\cdots+a_n\Bbb Z=\gcd(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @anon, if all the $a_i$ are nonzero, otherwise I disagree.

Comment: @Dylan Why? ${}$

Comment: Zero is not a problem.  But it is not easy for $0$ and $y$ to be coprime.

Comment: Since you know you can make 1, it should be clear that you can make any $k$ by adding up 1's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the set of all integer linear combinations of $x$ and $y$ is equal to the set of all multiples of their gcd, i.e.  $\{mx+ny: m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = d \mathbb{Z}$, where $d:=gcd(x,y)$.